# Standard Image Button Icons for iOS in Xcode

Tags: ios

Does anyone know where I can find the standard image icons (add, share, refresh, etc.) for iOS? Better yet, can someone direct me to a simple example of adding such a button to a tool bar? I can't seem to find one anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `- (id)initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItem)systemItem target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;` method to add `UIBarButtons` to your toolbar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:target action:action];
```

These are the types available

```
UIBarButtonSystemItemDone,
UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel,
UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit,  
UIBarButtonSystemItemSave,  
UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd,
UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace,
UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace,
UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose,
UIBarButtonSystemItemReply,
UIBarButtonSystemItemAction,
UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize,
UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks,
UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch,
UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh,
UIBarButtonSystemItemStop,
UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera,
UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash,
UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay,
UIBarButtonSystemItemPause,
UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind,
UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward,
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great. But can you show how I set the action? meaning, how do I call the function? (I'm very new to iOS dev)

Comment: the target will be the object which has the method implemented, and the action will be @selector(methodName)

Comment: It can be in which ever class you want, just that you should pass the corresponding object of that class in target.

Comment: Any recommendations on what to use for "Settings"?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the Apple Story board,

1. open the story board
2. click on the UIBarItem, then click on the sytem item as shown in the picture below.

You should be able to set the system icons from here.

[image: Click on the System Item]